# How much does RAM affect Androidstudio / Emulator Performance?

Tags: android, android-emulator, ram

My PC has 8GB of DDR3 Ram and an intel 2700k. When I run my Game on the Emulator it gets laggy, and on my Phone (galaxy s7) it runs very smooth. Is this due to RAM limitations? (The answer is most definitely yes to some degree as my RAM is at 96% capacity with only Chrome+Androidstudio+Emulator open)

Anybody got experience with doing a RAM upgrade and what performance improvement did you get?

Answer (score 2):

There are a few tweaks you could do.

1. Avoid keeping your tabs open on Chrome and use an alternate lightweight browser
2. Go to task manager> go to services > find studio64 and set its priority to high same for the emulator.
3. Avoid using the emulator and use a physical device instead. If you have to use the emulator i) keep it off during your development ii) allocate more ram to your emulator if you want a performance boost.
   To increase or decrease it .
   Go to Tools->Android->AVD Manager, there's something like a pencil to edit your AVD click on that, then in the pop-up window click Show Advanced Settings, and there, you can change the RAM size.

PS: use a non Play Store emulator (not verified but worked for me ). It is less laggy than the play store ones